# Generic method that take as input Breeze Vector or Breeze Matrix

Tags: scala, scala-breeze

I am trying to implement a method that can accept as input either a Breeze Vector or a Breeze Matrix. Something like

```
  private def updateExponentialMovingAverage[T](tau: Double, initTheta: T, theta: T): T = {
    tau * theta + (1 - tau) * initTheta
  }
```

However this raises an issue with overloading and I cannot find an appropriate type to restrict T. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breezes uses type classes for most of these kinds of things. The easiest thing to do is to use the `VectorSpace` type class, though unfortunately for DenseMatrices the VectorSpace typeclass is gated behind another import, which I regret.

```
import breeze.linalg._
import breeze.math._
import breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix.FrobeniusInnerProductDenseMatrixSpace.space

def updateExponentialMovingAverage[T](tau: Double, initTheta: T, theta: T)(implicit vs: VectorSpace[T, Double]): T = {
   import vs._
   theta * tau + initTheta * (1 - tau)
}

scala> val dv = DenseVector.rand(3)
val dv: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(0.21025028035007942, 0.6257503866073217, 0.8304592391242225)

scala> updateExponentialMovingAverage(0.8, dv, dv)
val res0: breeze.linalg.DenseVector[Double] = DenseVector(0.21025028035007942, 0.6257503866073217, 0.8304592391242225)

scala> val dm = DenseMatrix.rand(3, 3)
val dm: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double] = 0.6848513069340505  0.8995141354384266   0.3889904836678608  
0.4554398871938874  0.03297082723969558  0.6708501327709948  
0.4456539828672945  0.04289112062985678  0.9679002485942578  

updateExponentialMovingAverage(0.8, dm, dm)
val res1: breeze.linalg.DenseMatrix[Double] = 0.6848513069340505  0.8995141354384266   0.3889904836678608  
0.4554398871938874  0.03297082723969558  0.6708501327709948  
0.4456539828672945  0.04289112062985678  0.9679002485942578
```